# WindowsFormsApplication Number Generator

Tags: c#

I wish to know if i can make a simple application in WFA that if you enter your name to generate a lucky number, I have an idea but I really don't know how to generate a number if you insert your name...Is it even posible ?

Comment: Look at `Random` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Do you want a random number, or a number based upon the name - so the same name generates the same number?

Comment: _Yes!_....if you're lucky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# a string is composed of single characters and those can be converted to `int`

```
string s = "Abc";
int i = (int)s[0]; // Get code of first character.
```

Yet another possibility is to get the hash code of the string:

```
int hash = s.GetHashCode();
```

This hash code should look random enough. If not, or if you need to create several random numbers from a name, you could use this hash code as a seed value for the random numbers.

```
var random = new Random(hash);
int n1 = random.Next();
int n2 = random.Next();
```

Comment: I would not recommend `GetHashCode()`, from the op's description he wants the same output every time for a given input. GetHashCode() is only guaranteed to produce the same output for the same input per app-domain. `Random` is a little more reliable, however it is only guaranteed to generate the same output for a given input per within a major .NET version number. It you want a reliable mapping from input to out you need to provide a custom algorithm you have full control over.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var random = new Random();
var number = random.Next(0, 1000);
```

In this example, `number` is an `int` digit between 0 and 1000.